# In ReactJS, how to map object items coming in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, javascript-objects, redux-thunk

In ReactJS, how to map object items coming in redux state?

[image: I want to map "donor" as shown in this pic]

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
     console.log("state.donorReducer.donor" ,state.donorReducer.donor)
    return {
        donorReducer: state.donorReducer,
        donorslist: state.donorReducer.donor,
    }
}
```

How can I map donorslist items? 
I tried it ,

```
{this.props.donorReducer.donor.map((m, i) => {
                    return(
                      <div>

                        <Paper style={style} zDepth={5} > 
                        >Blood: {m.bloodgroup}<br />
                        >Mobile: {m.mobile}<br /> 
                        >Name: {m.fullname}<br />
                        >Age: {m.age}<br />
                        >Address: {m.address}<br />
                        </Paper>                     
                     </div>
  )
                })

                }
```

Comment: Do you get an errror. What is the problem

Comment: result is not showing   http://prntscr.com/ev2639

Comment: Well, using `>` sign in html is not the best idea. Try to remove the `>` before every line. Look at the generated element! (Inspect).

Comment: I removed but same error Uncaught TypeError: this.props.donorReducer.donor.map is not a function
    at DonorList.render (DonorList.js:96)

Comment: @NaveedAheer Note that before you load the data `donor` will be empty and you need to handle that case, e.g. using `this.props.donorReducer.donor || []`

Comment: You are right, I handled it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply map over the list like and remove the `>` signs before items

```
{this.props.donorslist && this.props.donorslist.map((m, i) => {
                    return(
                      <div>

                        <Paper style={style} zDepth={5} > 
                        Blood: {m.bloodgroup}<br />
                        Mobile: {m.mobile}<br /> 
                        Name: {m.fullname}<br />
                        Age: {m.age}<br />
                        Address: {m.address}<br />
                        </Paper>                     
                     </div>
                     )
            })

 }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.donorslist.map is not a function

Comment: Can you show the result of console.log(this.props.donorslist) in  your component

Comment: @NaveedAheer did u bind mapStateToProps to component using `connect` ?

Comment: @JSantosh That could be a problem as well apart from the data not being present initially

Comment: export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DonorList);

Comment: wrap `this.props.donorReducer.donor` inside `()`

Comment: Are you using immutableJS

Comment: @MayankShukla need my help for ??

Comment: Yes , I m using imutableJS

Comment: I got solution, actually I was passing an object which is not maped, I passed an arrey it worked, thanks a lot for my help